# This is my profile form . I can view the form but i cant edit nor click on any fields of the form

Tags: python, django, forms

[image]This is my models  . I have created abstract user instead of django built in user . I have also added image field

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from PIL import Image


class User(AbstractUser):
ROLES = (('0','Admin'),('1','Reporter'),('2','Guest'))
role = models.CharField(choices=ROLES, default='2', max_length= 1)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email',)

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dob = models.DateField(null= True, blank = True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is my signals . i have created so that I can have instant Profile after I register

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from accounts.models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
instance.profile.save()
```

this is my view.. I have done function based view.. this view contains 2 forms one for profile and other for username and firstname

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                instance= request.user.profile)
    if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
        u_form.save()
        p_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
else:
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

context = {
    'u_form':u_form,
    'p_form':p_form
}
return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. What does "I can't edit it" mean? What happens?

Comment: @DanielRoseman have you understood my problem now